# Alphabetical order (Visual studio 13)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to make a program that will show letters in alphabetical order from a to z and the number 
suitable for every letter . Here is my code:

```
int main(){
int i = 97; //starting point
int v = 0; //increment with this value
while (i<=122)
{
    cout << char('a' + v) << "\t" << i << endl;
    ++i;
    ++v;
}
```

Now the problem is that is showing only numbers from 100 to 122 and anything i tried , doesn't shows 97 , 98 , and 99 .. Have you guys faced with this problem and can you help me?

Comment: Works as you expect [Here](https://ideone.com/wosBj7) (even if not portable alphabet is not guaranty to be consecutive)...

Comment: Are you sure your console isn't just cutting off the first few outputs? Have you tried stepping through using the debugger?

Comment: @Jarod42 that's what i want to see , still not working .

Comment: @UnholySheep i tried that ..

Comment: Prefer to use character literals, instead of their decimal ASCII values.  You are already using `a`, so you can use `int i = 'a'` and `while (i <= 'z')`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use magic numbers, they will only get you in trouble.  You have two ways you can do this.  The first which is not totally portable is to just use a for loop like

```
for (char letter = 'a', letter <= 'z'; ++letter)
    std::cout << letter << " " << static_cast<int>(letter) << "\n";
```

This will break though if you ever use a character set where a-z is not contiguious.  If you really want to do it right you can use

```
std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (auto letter : alphabet)
    std::cout << letter << " " << static_cast<int>(letter) << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main() {
  int i = 97;  // starting point
  int v = 0;  // increment with this value
  while (i <= 122) {
    cout << char('a' + v) << '\t' << i << '\n';
    ++i;
    ++v;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
a   97
b   98
c   99
d   100
e   101
f   102
g   103
h   104
i   105
j   106
k   107
l   108
m   109
n   110
o   111
p   112
q   113
r   114
s   115
t   116
u   117
v   118
w   119
x   120
y   121
z   122
```

By the way for a little performance improvement, use '\n' over std::endl

Comment: Thanks , I will use that . Yours works perfectly , mine is rusty I think xD

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution given by Nathan, here is another one, pretty similar:

```
#include <iostream>

const int ALPHABET_LETTERS_COUNT = 26;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_LETTERS_COUNT; i++)
        std::cout << static_cast<char>('a' + i) << '\t' << static_cast<int>('a' + i) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ALPHABET_LETTERS` is misnamed, `ALPHABET_LETTERS_COUNT` would be more appropriate.